# How can i get list of all the orders place by user in Magento2 using rest api

Tags: rest, react-native, magento2

Iam developing react-native application and using Magento2 REST API, How can i get list of all the orders place by user.

Comment: What you done so far?

Comment: Yup thanks for asking i have solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am using this url to get the list of orders placed by user in Magento2.

`baseurl/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_email&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=aaa@gmail.com`

place user email in the place of aaa@gmail.com, and we need to pass access token in header using GET method.